# how to get result set in Redshift procedure after commit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I'm creating procedures in Redshift. I want to add a select statement to verify the results before the END statement but it doesn't work.

This works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$                
BEGIN (a whole bunch of select into statements)
commit;
END;
$$;
```

But when I use a "select count(*) cnt from table" after the commit I get an error such as

"COMMIT cannot be invoked from a procedure that is executing in an atomic context"

I'm aware that I can create my_procedure(current refcursor), which works without a commit, but I couldn't get it to work with the commit:

```
open current for select count(*) cnt from table_name;
```

It seems SQL Server returns select statements while performing the inserts. How to do in Redshift?

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you are calling the stored procedure from within an open transaction. See the examples for `TRUNCATE` in the ["Managing transactions"  documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-transaction-management.html).

You can see some examples of Redshift stored procedures that use `COMMIT` in our [Redshift Utils repo on GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/). In particular, [`sp_sync_get_new_rows`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_sync_get_new_rows.sql) uses `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` conditionally.